Vega-Lite: Add custom inline CSS for each mark item
In my React app, I would like to render an SVG-based chart with Vega-Lite where each mark can be customized to get its own inline CSS?
But the CSS is different for each item (the view-transition-name).
Something like a function that is being called for each item to customize the rendered output.
Is that even possible?
Thanks in advance!
